# Return scheduled posts with WP REST API

Tags: permissions, api, json, scheduled-posts, wp-api

I'm using [WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/) plugin for a custom web application and I need to get access to the scheduled posts of the target wordpress website. However I can't find any parameter or filter to achieve this on the [documentation](http://wp-api.org/).

Have tried passing the future date of a post in the API request query string but nothing returns.

Tried to get a future (scheduled) post by passing directly his id with `/wp-json/posts/57117` and I get an error response.

```
[{"code":"json_user_cannot_read","message":"Sorry, you cannot read this post."}]
```

How is the right way to access the data for scheduled posts? They are not password protected, just scheduled. This needs authentication somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, dropping it here in case someone need it.

> You need to be logged in as a user that has the `edit_posts` capability. With that capability, you also get access to the private query vars, including `post_status`.

Taken from [this similar issue](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/325).